# How to solve this using Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Write Prolog program that reads the students grades in AI class and keep reading until “stop” is read. Find the number of students whose grades are:

- Between 93 - 100
- Between 83 and less than 92

```
grade(MARKS) :-
    MARKS<100, MARKS>=93,
    write('Number of student with grades between 93 to 100 is'),nl.

grade(MARKS):-
    MARKS<92, MARKS>=83,
    write('Number of student with grades between 83 to less than 92 is'),nl.
```

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm finds the number of students with the given grade ranges in the following lists.

```
grade10 :-        
Marks=[50,93,99],aggregate_all(count,(member(Mark,Marks),grade1(Mark)),Val),write('Number of student with grades between 93 to 100 is '),writeln(Val).

grade1(Mark) :-
    Mark<100, Mark>=93.

grade20 :-        
Marks=[50,83,91,100],aggregate_all(count,(member(Mark,Marks),grade2(Mark)),Val),write('Number of student with grades between 83 to less than 92 is '),writeln(Val).

grade2(Mark):-
    Mark<92, Mark>=83.
```

The outputs is as follows:

```
?- grade10.
Number of student with grades between 93 to 100 is 2
true.

?- grade20.
Number of student with grades between 83 to less than 92 is 2
true.
```